# EmailMessage 'sender' issue

Tags: django, email

i am working on a contact form to receive emails from users. I am using EmailMessage(django 1.3). the problem is, i am able to receive the emails but the 'from'or 'sender' shows  email_host_user email instead of the user's email.

so if user has email address user@gmail.com, when i receive the email

```
from: email@gmail.com
subject: some subject
to: moderator@email.com
```

instead of

```
from: user@gmail.com
subject: some subject
to: moderator@email.com
```

heres a part of the settings

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.googlemail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'email@gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
REVIEW_MODERATOR ='moderator@email.com'

#heres part of the helpers.py
def run(self):
            html = get_template(self.kwargs['template'])
            html_content = html.render(Context(self.kwargs['context']))
            msg = EmailMessage(
                       self.kwargs['subject'],
                       html_content,
                       self.kwargs['sender'],
                       [self.kwargs['email']],
                       bcc=[a[1] for a in settings.ADMINS])
            msg.content_subtype = "html"  # Main content is now text/html
            try:
                path = self.kwargs['file_path']
            except KeyError:
                pass
            else:
                msg.attach_file(path)
            msg.send()

#heres part of the contact view

if contact_form.is_valid(): 
            cdata = contact_form.cleaned_data

            c={'name':cdata['name'], 'email':cdata['email'],'message':cdata['message']}    

            EmailThread(**{
                'email':settings.REVIEW_MODERATOR,
                'sender':cdata['email'],
                'subject':email_subject,
                'context':c,
                'template':template
            }).start()
```

Answer (score 1):

Gmail doesn't let you send as arbitrary senders.

The way around this problem (I was dealing with the exact issue: customer service forms that send us email) is to use one of a very inexpensive SMTP services, or just settle with "reply-to" headers which are still quite functional (email is from from me@gmail.com but clicking reply will point to the reply-to address).